# How to add "title" attribute of option tag when using JTHML in Joomla

Tags: joomla

"option" tag has "title" attribute to display extra information about element.
But when I create a selection in Joomla with JHTML, for example:

```
JHTML::_('select.option', $elementId, $elementName);
```

I can't add "title" attribute to my elements.

Is there any way we could add "title" attribute to "select.option" when using JHTML?

Thank you for answers!

Comment: Perhaps this is a better alternative: http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/HTML/JHtmlSelect.html?#methodgenericlist

Answer (score 1):

```
JHTML::_('select.option', $elementId, $elementName, $optKey);
```

You should look in the file `/libraries/joomla/html/html/select.php`. It has a little bit of documentation, maybe that works for you. Besides, the title attribute does not exist for the HTML `<option>` tag, as you can see in the following link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp

Comment: Actually the title attribute exists for the option tag. Title is one of the global attributes  that can be used with all HTML elements: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp